# ASP.NET 3.5 calling [WebMethod] with AJAX - 500 Error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I have a Web Site Project (ASP.NET 3.5).

One of the methods is in Search.aspx.cs looks like this. This is a method I am trying to call so I can return some data to Ajax call:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string TestMethod(string param)
    {
        return "It worked";
    }
```

Having difficulty calling the above method from client side button click from inside the Search.aspx page :

```
<form runat="server" id="mainForm" class="form-horizontal">
<input id="addButton" type="button" value="Add" />
</form>

<script>
$('#addButton').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "Search.aspx/TestMethod",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("We returned: " + result);
                }
            });
        });

</script>
```

Here is the screen showing alert box from error ajax function.

[image]

Here is another from Firefox debugger:

[image]

Here is a screenshot with a complete error from Firefox debugger:

[image]

Comment: Can you make the firfox debugger Screenshot more readable?

Comment: also do you get an error in your server code when you are debugging? If so what does it say? If not that means IIS is throwing the error and it would be in your IIS logs.

Comment: @JasonRoell I run this trough visual studio not IIS. I have a break point set in code behind it is not triggered.

Comment: Try with `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`

Comment: @Dalorzo I tried ... getting the same error.

Comment: Your application is hosted by IIS. That is what is handleing the request and then spinning up a worker process to run your application code. If you look at the response headers you can clearly see Server: "Microsoft-IIS/8.0". This means IIS 8.0 is handling the request and passing back to you the 500 Server Error. The "Server" it is referring to is your IIS Server.

Comment: I think the default place for access logs is

c:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles
Otherwise, check under IIS Manager, select the computer on the left pane, and in the middle pane, go under "Logging" in the IIS area. There you will se the default location for all sites (this is however overridable on all sites)

You could also look into

C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR
Which will contain similar log files that only represents error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your method expects to receive a parameter...

change your method to this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string TestMethod()
{
    return "It worked";
}
```

Or change your js to this (you have to use POST type):

```
<script>
$('#addButton').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Search.aspx/TestMethod",
                data: JSON.stringify({ "param" : "anything"}),
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("We returned: " + result);
                }
            });
        });

</script>
```

Comment: I still get the same error somewhere between Ajax is trying to make a call and that call reaching a code behind method somthing preventing it form making the call? Is there something that has to be set in web.config or anywhere to be able to do that? I have not done any of this, project has default settings?

Comment: Nice ... it says "An attempt was made to call the method 'TestMethod' using a GET request, which is not allowed." Not sure if that is helpful.

Comment: do you has changed the param "type" to "POST" like the example above?

Comment: It worked with POST. However I am not posting any data I want to get data so it shouldn't it be GET? For example I would pass in an ID and it would return a bunch of data based on that ID.

Comment: you dont have to use Get. you can keep this id on an input hidden like this: <input id="sampleId" type="hidden" value="3" />, and use in the post:
"data: JSON.stringify({ "param" : $("#sampleId").val() }),". do you understood?